# Using innerHTML.repalce to replace text with img element

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, innerhtml

I'm writing a [script](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LYQEpSTw) to add extra smileys to the Gmail chat.
Its working partially, i'm stuck with the innerHTML.replace method @line 33

If you see, the regex in the replace method is passed using a variable. This is where the script is choking.
If i replace the variable with the actual regex, it works fine :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each timeout closure ends up with the latest value for the two variables, not the value for the current iteration.  In the code, there's only one iteration, but I assume that's just simplified for posting.  You can change it to something like:

```
for(var i = smileys.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    (function(i)
    {
        var smileyRegex = smileys[i][0];
        var smileySrc = smileys[i][1];
        if(node.textContent.match(smileyRegex)) {
            log('match');
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                log(node.innerHTML); log(node.innerHTML.replace(smileyRegex, '<img class="smiley_ext" src="'+smileySrc+'">'));
            },1000);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

This way, each iteration step has its own set of variables.  However, I'm not sure whether you actually need the timeout.

Comment: aah, dumb me... off to change it :)

Comment: Although this is a good point and it should be fixed, it might not be the problem in this case because `smileys` has a length of 1 so there would only be one iteration.  Unless, of course, the OP has cut his code down in the pastebin sample provided.

Comment: Yeah Andy, i've cut down the code.
And i've got it working by passing the variables to the function.
It's all working fine now.
Thanks a tonne Matthew =)

Comment: ideally the timeout isn't needed, but this script is for Gmail, and aparently, without the timeout, it replaces the text with a smiley for a second & then replaces it back with the text. Hence i'm forced to use the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    log(node.innerHTML); 
    log(node.innerHTML.replace(smileyRegex, '<img class="smiley_ext" src="'+smileySrc+'">'));
},1000);
```

Use

```
(function(smileyRegex, smileySrc) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        log(node.innerHTML); 
        log(node.innerHTML.replace(smileyRegex, '<img class="smiley_ext" src="'+smileySrc+'">'));
    },1000);
})(smileyRegEx, smileySrc);
```

This is going to create scoped references to the values and so it wont be affected by the loop.